# Stuck installing new video drivers

Tags: drivers

Im following this http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide to install the drivers but Im stuck at the point of the warning not to use the following steps because Im running 14.04.2.
The guide does not say how I should proceed and Im a new Linux user. Any help would be greatly appreciated.                                                                    Just wondering but if i just use the option for fglrx in additional drivers, will that save me a headache? Its for steam and PoL.

Comment: What kind of video card?

Comment: Why do you try to install drivers this way? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry. its a radeon 5450HD

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. EAH5450 SILENT/DI/512MD2 (LP)
 Kernel driver in use: radeon